# OpenSSL Certificate For IDEAL

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, integration, sha256

I have been creating a website to link into an Advanced Integration with IDEAL. The issue is when I am creating the self signed certificates and loading them into the site, I am receiving this error:

Failure Signing Data: error:0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad password read - SHA256

I have followed the instructions to create these certificates and keys from the instructions given by IDEAL.

Here are the commands I have been writing in OPENSSL:

genrsa –des3 –out priv.pem –passout pass:pass 2048

req –x509 –sha1 –new –key priv.pem –passin pass:pass –days 3650 –out cert.cer

Could anyone point in the direction of where the mistake/error lies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the passphrase:

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out key_unprot.pem
```